# Problem with Oracle Sql Loader control file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, ora-01722

I'm trying to load some data using sql loader.  Here is the top of my control/data file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
APPEND INTO TABLE economic_indicators
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(ASOF_DATE DATE 'DD-MON-YY',
VALUE FLOAT EXTERNAL,
STATE,
SERIES_ID INTEGER EXTERNAL,
CREATE_DATE DATE 'DD-MON-YYYY')
BEGINDATA
01-Jan-79,AL,67.39940538,1,23-Jun-2009
```

... lots of other data lines.

The problem is that sql loader won't recognize the data types I'm specifying.  This is the log file:

```
Table ECONOMIC_INDICATORS, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: APPEND

Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
ASOF_DATE                           FIRST     *   ,       DATE DD-MON-YY       
VALUE                                NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER            
STATE                                NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER            
SERIES_ID                            NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER            
CREATE_DATE                          NEXT     *   ,       DATE DD-MON-YYYY     

value used for ROWS parameter changed from 10000 to 198
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table ECONOMIC_INDICATORS, column VALUE.
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

... lots of similiar errors, expected if trying to insert char data into a numeric column.

I've tried no datatype spec, all other numeric specs, and always the same issue.  Any ideas?

Also, any ideas on why it's changing the Rows parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example, SQL*Loader will try to evaluate the string "AL" to a number value, which will result in the error message you gave. The sample data has something looking like it could be a decimal number at third position, not second as specified int he column list.